# Concatenate two string in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, concatenation

Is possible to concatenate a static text and a binding value in the same attribute?
I want to concat this:

```
{Binding Text1}
```

And this

```
{x:Static resource:AppResources.text2}
```

On the same attribute. I have tried the following, but it doesn't works:

```
Text="{Binding Title} {x:Static resource:AppResources.idiomapaciente}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stringformat concatenates databinding and resource's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852050/stringformat-concatenates-databinding-and-resources-value)

Comment: Multi-bindings and Spans will both do what you're looking for